# Unable to cast object of type ServiceCollection to type 'Autofac.ContainerBuilder' using dotnet core and autofac

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I am trying to use `autofac` in my `dotnet core 3.1` project, but I am unable to run project after writing `ConfigureContainer` inside the `startup.cs` file.

```
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        var databaseConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");

        builder.RegisterModule(new MediatorModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule(databaseConnectionString));
    }
```

The error I am getting is :

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection' to type
>   'Autofac.ContainerBuilder'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureContainerAdapter`1.ConfigureContainer(HostBuilderContext
>   hostContext, Object containerBuilder)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
>   Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\src\Program.cs:line 39

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Autofac in the first place? .Net core supports native dependency injection

Comment: I had the same error when migrated from WebHostBuilder to generic HostBuilder and used `return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices(p => p.AddAutofac())`. Earlier it worked for `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices(p => p.AddAutofac())`. The correct way to fix this is like @Cyril Durand answered. In short: use `.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())`.
My problem is described well here: https://mderriey.com/2018/08/02/autofac-integration-in-asp-net-core-generic-hosts/

Comment: @EmilianoJavierGonzález because it lets you do things that the built in IoC doesn't

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When you configure your host you should call `UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ASP.NET Core 3.0+:
    // The UseServiceProviderFactory call attaches the
    // Autofac provider to the generic hosting mechanism.
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                   .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                   .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder => {
                       webHostBuilder
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseIISIntegration()
                        .UseStartup<Startup>();
                   })
                   .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Without this, .net core will create a `ServiceCollection` instead of a `ContainerBuilder` and an `InvalidCastException` will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot, '.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())' was missing in my 'HostBuilderConfig'.

Comment: These hosting changes with using service provider factory are acceptable only for ASP.NET Core 3.0+ versions

Comment: nice answer. for a further usage everyone should refer to a MSDN -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-dependency-injection-di-container